# How to close program when it crash?

Tags: bash, watchdog

I have bash script as follows:

```
while [ 1 ]; do
    <my_command>
done
```

If I simulate the end of program with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it restart the program again. However if the program ends because temporary internet connection lost, it does not stop properly, and thus it does not start again.

Error message during the connection lost ends with:

```
stack trace:
backtrace() returned 16 addresses
malloc_consolidate(): invalid chunk size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The program hangs with this message, and does not finish properly. Is there a simple way how to manage the program restart?

My idea is to monitor CPU/GPU utilization/temperature and kill the hanging program when the computer is not working (so it can start again with my script), but I wonder if there is a simpler way.

**Update:**
After more experiments I realized that disconnection of the computer (from my side of the Internet) not always leads to the hanging error. It seems that the hang end appears only at specific occasions. So I have limited ability to test it in short time.

Comment: Try adding an option: `set -e` at the beginning of the script

Comment: @nezabudka I will try. Thanks.

Comment: maybe you can use `ss` to look for the connection and send a kill if the connection fails.